# How to stop AVSpeechSynthesizer playback in the middle?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, text-to-speech, avspeechsynthesizer

I am using AVSpeechSynthesizer for text-to-speech in my app. Is it possible to stop the playback in the middle, e.g. if the user hits a stop button?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looking at the [Documentation for AVSpeechSynthesizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html), you need to call `-[AVSpeechSynthesizer pauseSpeakingAtBoundary:]` to stop speaking, and, then `-[AVSpeechSynthesizer continueSpeaking]` to continue speaking again afterwards.

You can choose to pause speaking right away (`AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate`), or, at the end of the current word (`AVSpeechBoundaryWord`).

Comment: Hello, I can't Stop on any button tapped, I want to stop it when cancel button pressed.
I tried as below:
if(av_speechSynthesizer.isSpeaking || av_speechSynthesizer){
do something
}

Comment: Instead of "pauseSpeakingAtBoundary:" use [AVSpeechSynthesizer stopSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];

Answer (score 9):

In swift:

```
synthesizer.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)
```

or

```
synthesizer.stopSpeaking(at: .word)
```